# How to select from two different tables using Inner Join

Tags: sql-server

I have two tables `Userdb` and `Approval`. Both tables have a common column but different names (`LanID` & `UserID`). In the `Userdb`, there are columns `LanID, Name, DepartmentName`.

I need to show these records :

1. His own records
2. All records in the same department

My current code:

```
SELECT 
    Userdb.LanID, Approval.UserID
FROM 
    Userdb_table, Approval_table  
JOINS
    Approval_table ON Userdb.LanID = Approval.UserID
```

My current code does not fulfill the second condition, how can I do that?

Comment: use conditions along with joins.

Comment: Sample Data and output will help !

Comment: I agree with Avi, some toy data examples would help.  But to show all records in the *same* department?  I would say borrow @Guarav's example and add this condition: SELECT ut.LanID, ut.Name, ut.DepartmentName FROM Userdb_table ut INNER JOIN Approval_table at ON ut.LanID = at.UserID WHERE ut.DepartmentName = 'A'

Answer (score 1):

Please note the way you are joining the two tables(comma separated join) is not recommended and should be avoided. You can use below query to get the result. I am assuming that you want these three columns in select list to be displayed, if you want something else from Approval_table  also you can add those in select statement. I hope it will help.

```
  SELECT ut.LanID, ut.Name, ut.DepartmentName
  FROM Userdb_table ut INNER JOIN Approval_table at
  ON ut.LanID = at.UserID
```

Comment: @Angel Lim, if you're wondering *why* the older comma separated style isn't recommended, this is worth a look: https://stackoverflow.com/a/1018877/5590742  (tldr: INNER JOIN is more human readable)